# How do I mock out a call to a WCF Service when using a Send or SendReceive activity in WF4?

Tags: workflow, mocking, workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4

So as apart of my workflow I need to make a call to an external WCF Service to retrieve some objects.  The problem is I can't see how to mock out the WCF Service that will be called by the send activity.  Does anyone know how I can do this?

Thanks,
John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best answer I've found so far comes from Ron Jacobs who has done a couple of blog posts on this post using his XamlInjector.  This is the latest one:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rjacobs/archive/2011/01/20/wf4-how-to-unit-test-a-workflow-that-calls-a-wcf-service.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap it in your own interface/class so that it could be mocked, or you could mock it with the interface that is included in the generated code:

```
public partial class FooClient : System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<YourApp.FooService.IFooService>, YourApp.EntitiesService.IFooService { 
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Unfortunately that's not possible, as the send and receive activities use the ChannelFactory under the covers and so there's no way of replacing the object that comes back.